# Como muestro estos datos en mysql

Tags: php

Quiero mostrar esto en mi página php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esto para conectarla:

`$sql_dbbase = "SELECT * from dbase";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres obtener la fila esa sería de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql_dbbase = "SELECT * from dbase where id=1";
```

O si deseas obtener solo la columla ID sería:

```
$sql_dbbase = "select id from dbase";
```

Comment: Gracias! Eso es lo que buscaba, pero si en una misma tabla quiero poner el id 0 y el id 1, tengo que cerrar y volver abrir las llaves no?

Comment: No solo deberías poner 

$sql_dbbase = "SELECT * from dbase where id=1 OR id=0";

Así te mostrara las dos filas.

Comment: El tema es que quiero que en un `<li>` este el dato que está en el id 0 y mas abajo, adentro del mismo `if {}` este otro `<li>` con el dato del id 1, me explico?

Comment: Pues en la manera que recorres lo que te devuelve la consulta, es ahí donde debe poner esa condicional.

Comment: No entendí esa parte.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, cerre y volví a abrir cada if y sus respectiva `{}`